# How to get page parameters in Lift snippet?

Tags: scala, lift

I have a simple lift page:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <span id="content" class="lift:GetContent"></span>
   </body>
</html>
```

and a simple snippet:

```
class GetContent {
  def render = "#content" #> "someValue"
}
```

The question is, how can I get the parameter, which is passed in URL (like `page.html?param=value`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When your snippet class is instantiated, the parameters are available in [S.param](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4-M4/#net.liftweb.http.S):

```
class GetContent {
  val param = S.param("param") openOr "No parameter given"
  def render = "#content" #> param
}
```